# Docusign API - pulling account's custom tags

Tags: docusignapi

Does the Docusign REST API support pulling back all custom tags available for an account?  The custom tags I'm referring to are found in Preferences -> Member Options -> Custom Tags.  We're wanting to build a drag-n-drop interface for inserting available custom tags in our sales documents.  I did review the documentation (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm), but didn't find what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That capability isn't yet exposed in our APIs but is something we are considering for a future release.

Answer (score 0):

This is now available via a call to GET `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/tab_definitions`

See https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/CustomTabs/CustomTabs/list/